# Vector ImageButton in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a vector as an ImageButton in RecyclerView and I get `NotFoundException`. The path is correct...And other Images works.

heres the code:

```
public class Todo_DataGenerator {
public static List<Todo_SampleClass> getData(Context context){
    List<Todo_SampleClass> Notes=new ArrayList<>();
    Todo_SampleClass Note=new Todo_SampleClass();
    Note.setTitle("Title");
    Note.setContent("Content");
    Note.setImgbtn_edit(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_edit_black_24dp,null));

    Note.setImggbtn_remove(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp,null));

    Notes.add(Note);

    return Notes;
   }
}
```

I want to Display each View with (Title, Content and 2 ImageButton) how should I do that?

And which `LayoutManager` I should use for `RelativeLayout`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, id);` instead .

also, make sure you have the vector drawables inside the drawable folder.

Comment: Thanks...now where should i set the onClickListener ?

Comment: you didnot mention sth about listener in the question?